# Unify tag names

Tags: discussion, tags

Many of our tag names are pretty inconsistent. So we e.g. have:

[text-editors](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-editors), [html-editor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html-editor), [audio-editing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-editing), [video-editing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-editing), [image-processing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing), [image-editing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-editing), [image-editor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-editor)

and several others in this line. Those examples show the following inconsistencies:

- singular vs. plural forms (editor / editors)
- nominalized verbs versus nomens (editing / editor)

All in all, it looks a bit messy. Shouldn't we clean this up? If so, what should our guidelines be? Can we adapt them somehow from any matured SE site, to stay even consistent "at large"?

**EDIT:**

Yes, I'm aware that only mods can rename a tag (see: [How to rename a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87437/192154)). If we feel it's worth it, that's the way to go. If not: I'd prefer keeping the "status-quo" over creating redundancy by using synonyms only differing in their last 1..3 characters.

#### Singular vs. plural tags

There seems to be a consent on always using plural forms for tags (with few exceptions where plural doesn't make sense):

- [Tags should be plurals (with a few caveats)](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/tags-should-be-plurals-with-a-few-caveats) (Meta.Travel.SE)
- [Tag Etiquette - Gerunds versus Plurals (or tagging vs. tags)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48017/192154) (Meta.SE)
- [Is the tag pluralization filter working correctly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187406/192154) (Meta.SE; this post shows that there even has been a mechanism to not allow singular tags being created); also see: [Why is the tag [layouts] replaced with [layout] instead of the other way around?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75675/192154)

#### Forms: nominalized verbs vs. plural forms

Here it seems might be more exceptions, as different forms might have different meanings. Still, if that's not the case, we might want to set a preference:

- [What's the difference between [flags] and [flagging]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116334/192154)

#### Speaking of guidelines...

- [What's the deal with retagging from UK English to US English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48958/192154)
- [What should the standard spelling be - British or US?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23869/192154) (not strictly tag-related ;)
- [We should NOT have hybrid tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190540/192154)

Comment: plural vs. sigular: The guideline is [plural](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/600) as long as it makes sense (see the link).

Comment: @AngeloFuchs I knew it was somewhere. Thanks for digging it up!

Comment: As [Angelo pointed out](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1129/185) it might not be worth the trouble (and I see his point in that at least partly), we should at least decide for future tags: Apart from [always using plural forms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187406/192154), do we want to have `*ors` or `*ings` – or doesn't that matter at all? I'm not speaking of possible exceptions (where there is no "ing/ors", or they are describing different things), but a general guideline.

Answer (score -3):

I think its not worth the trouble. We should stick with whats used the most currently and synonym new tags to that.

To ease up that process we should up-vote the M.SE discussions that aim at improving the tag-synonym process.

1. [Allow people with domain knowledge vote on synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210617/168963)
2. [Improve the Tag Synonyms in general](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204244/168963)
3. [Fix ambiguous tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125234/168963) in cases where a synonym doesn't cut it.
4. [Mass-Retagging-Queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137706/168963) to make it easier when something to fix pops up.

Comment: I disagree with "simply create synonyms". AFAIK *renaming* a tag (as opposed to "retagging") is not too difficult a task (mods: correct me if I'm wrong here). When adding a tag to a question, people start typing – and the right one pops up before they are ready (i.e. in most cases they'll click it before having typed the suffix) – which is what synonyms are for usually (lead to the correct tag), so they would be superflous here (and just make a bigger mess).

Comment: @Izzy renaming requires a mod. Creating synonyms does not. My point is that whatever you do, wrong tags will reemerge until you synonym them to the right one. So you can skip the renaming step and go directly to the synonym step.

Comment: I see your point – but still disagree. It makes no sense to me to duplicate the tags into synonyms just differing by the last 1..3 characters. Last time I checked we had more than one mod. So if this is felt important enough and agreed to by the mods, one of them should do the renaming. If not, I'd prefer keeping the "status quo" over creating redundancy.